# Daily plot report Axis Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am plotting the data of one day. I get the values from a CSV file. One column is the time `hh:mm:ss` and the other my data. I plot a XY - Chart. For all of this I am using VBA.

The chart should always start at `00:00` and end at `24:00`. So I set minimum to `0` and maximum to `1`. But the axis now have values from `00:00` to `00:00`. I played around a little bit but can't find a solution for this

Comment: Could you please provide us with the code you have so far? Stack Overflow is not a coding service ;-)

Comment: sry but I think if you are argumenting this way I think you couldn't answer the question. Because as I said I set the minimum and maximum scale and I think I don't need to post these two commands :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `00:00:00` is the same as `24:00:00`. You need to format the chart axis to 24hr format

Try this. Amend as applicable.

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it is working. But I am using [hh] because I like the leading zero to keep the format constant.

Comment: Then use `[hh]:mm:ss` and not `hh:mm:ss`. There is a difference :)

Comment: Yes. I am using [hh]:mm

Comment: ok. I used "[h]:mm:ss" in my code to demonstrate the conversion :) Glad it is sorted.